# qtcreator source from github - can't resolve qbs reference

Tags: git, github, qt-creator, qbs

always when I was trying to clone qtcreator repository I had a errors with submodule qbs, I was ignoring this because was not important on that moment.

however today I need to check this out without issues. so the error is still there. not sure that is the same like was previously.

Is there anyone who also faced with it and successfully resolved this?

> fatal: reference is not a tree:
>   1a103f7a90b51022aa10da228deb566cd7b446ca Unable to checkout
>   '1a103f7a90b51022aa10da228deb566cd7b446ca' in submodule path
>   'src/shared/qbs'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the mirrors hadn't been updated. It's fixed now.